# linux globbing library?

Tags: linux, glob

Is there a library for linux that implements globbing functionality ?

I'm not talking about the glob/fnmatch/etc functions, because I'm not talking about evaluating the glob expression(s) against the filesystem. The API would include a list, and an expression, and return a new list.

Basically an anlog of libpcre but for executing glob expressions. Is there such a thing already ?

Answer (score 0):

fnmatch does not execute against the filesystem, so should solve your problem. Here is the signature of fnmatch:

> int fnmatch(const char *pattern, const char *string, int flags);

The **pattern** is your glob expression and it is evaluated against a given **string**. No file system is involved